# When I know that I have a capacity miss in direct-mapped or N-associative cache?

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture

I'm trying to make a cache simulator and it's necessary count the number of Compulsory Misses, Capacity Misses and Conflict Misses, but I don't know how count the number of Capacity Misses at the direct-mapped and N-associative caches. I have been search on Stack (and in others sources) about it, but the others answers didn't help me.

I KNOW the definition of each C misses, I just don't know  that specific case with the capacity miss.

Anybody to help me?

Comment: Any miss that is not compulsory or conflict (or coherence, i.e., from invalidation of a cache line to maintain coherence) is attributed to capacity. (The three [or four] C model of cache misses is only a high level model. A contrived access pattern can have a lower miss rate for a direct-mapped cache than for a fully associative LRU-replacement cache; a *negative* conflict miss rate could lead to a higher capacity miss count than total miss count.)

Comment: Hi Paul! Thanks for the help. Your're really right. In the cache direct-mapped  or set-associative the number of capacity misses it's the misses that isn't compulsory or conflict. So, in my simulator, if I want count the number of capacity misses, I have to do the other simulate in a cache full associative.

Answer (score 1):

For a set associative cache, I would say that a miss can be classified as *capacity* if the same access would miss in a fully associative cache of the same capacity (ignoring cold misses). Some may disagree with me, understandably, since it's tricky to define it exactly like this.

I've heard other definitions state that a miss is a *conflict* and not *capacity* if the requested data was evicted while there were still unused sets.